# Getting Issue while building hystrix

Tags: java, jna, netflix, hystrix, nebula

Initially I had a issue of :

Build Error : A problem occurred configuring root project 'hystrix'.> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.

> JNA native support (com/sun/jna/linux-ppc64le/libjnidispatch.so) not found in resource path.

I put jna.jar to /jre/lib/ext folder so that solved the JNA native support error,

Now I have been with the following error.

```
 ./gradlew --stacktrace build
Inferred project: hystrix, version: 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file '/root/ravi/watson/Netflix/Hystrix/hystrix-contrib/hystrix-clj/build.gradle' line: 13
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':hystrix-clj'.
 clojuresque.ClojureBasePlugin
* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':hystrix-clj'.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$1.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:148)
```

Can any of you people plz look into it.

Thanks,
Salamani

Comment: build.gradle file is as follow <br/> `buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven{
          name 'clojars'
          url 'http://clojars.org/repo'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.netflix.nebula:nebula-clojure-plugin:1.12.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'nebula-clojure' // this is a wrapper around clojuresque to make it behave well with other plugins

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    clojarsRepo()
}`
...

Comment: Don't add additional code in the comments, update your question instead.